ogrinfo issues when updating row record with sqlite dialect
I am using the following ogrinfo call to update a row record (where name is "50mn_R9_R10"):
ogrinfo tmp.shp -dialect sqlite -sql 'update tmp set iacolor=case when name="50mn_R9_10" then "amber" end'

The problem appears when I update the next record (ie. name is "50mn_R10_R11" and iacolor is 'red') because it deletes the previous updated row record (ie. 'amber' is deleted where name is "50mn_R9_R10"):
ogrinfo tmp.shp -dialect sqlite -sql 'update tmp set iacolor=case when name="50mn_R10_11" then "red" end'

What am I doing wrong here? Any hints are much appreciated.

No WHERE clause?

you were right, it was missing, thanks for pointing that out!

Best add this as answer and mark it as excepted so it is immedietely clear to everyone that it is solved...

Thanks to @jarlh, the right ogrinfo call is as follows:
ogrinfo tmp.shp -dialect sqlite -sql 'update tmp set iacolor="amber" where name="50mn_R9_10"'

So, other row records can be updated programmatically once the desired field (in this case "iacolor") is changed based on another field (in this case "name").
